# bulding chromium sandbox: the SYSTEMROOT error

Tags: chromium

I'm doing everything as suggested [here](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows), but got stuck with

```
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\depot_tools\python276_bin\lib\multiproce
sing\pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: Environment variable "SYSTEMROOT" required to be set to valid path
Error: Command 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\depot_tools\\python276_bin\\
ython.exe src/build/gyp_chromium' returned non-zero exit status 1 in C:\Users\A
ministrator\Desktop\chromium
Hook ''C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' src
build/gyp_chromium' took 164.66 secs
```

while running gclient runhooks.

Any help? Also I just need the sandbox, could there be any precompiled binaries anywhere?

Comment: Did you cloned the code or copied from a different system?

Comment: Try running gclient sync instead of gclient runhooks. And also have you set all Var paths ?

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem: I had VS2015 along with VS2013 and the script looked for C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat, which wasn't there for some reason. Uninstalling VS2015 did the trick